# Keep updating list while summing

Tags: python

I'm a begginer in Python. I need help. 
I recieve a starting point (in this case, (2, 0)) and must sum 2 numbers to that. Eg (2, 0) + (1, 1) = (3, 1).
I have to keep doing this till I achieve a maximum value (in this case 5) of elements is the list.

But I have a problem. I can't make a loop and keep updating the list. 
The function must work with any value. Can someone help me?
Here is what I have (know it's wrong, but i'm stuck):

```
def summ(a, b):
    return (a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1])

x= (((5), (2,0), (1,1)))

maxx= x[0] #max of elements in list
start= x[1] #starting point
direction= x[2] #what it must sum

def position(x):

    new_list= ()

    for i in x:
        new_list = start, summ(start, direction)
        new_list += (summ(new_list[-1], direction), )
        if len(new_list) == maxx:
            break

    return new_list

#the output I had
((2, 0), (3, 1), (4, 2))

#the output I need
((2, 0), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 3), (6, 4)) #5 elements, maxx
```

Comment: move the `new_list = start, summ(start, direction)` outside of the for loop.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
def summ(a, b):
    return a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1]


x = 5, (2, 0), (1, 1)


def position(x):
    i = 1
    new_list = [x[i]]

    while i < x[0]:
        new_list += summ(new_list[i - 1], x[2]),
        i = i + 1

    return new_list


print(position(x))
```

Tested and the OUTPUT is

[(2, 0), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 3), (6, 4)]

Comment: I just added to the return: tuple(new_list). So the output will be ((2,0), (3,1), (4,2), (5,3), (6,4)). Thank you! :)

Answer (score -1):

Use a list comprehension:

```
a = ((5,), (2,0), (1,1))

b = [(a[1][0] + i*a[2][0], a[1][1] + i*a[2][1]) for i in range(a[0][0])]
```